# Trouble with output function C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, printing, output

I am having trouble getting this program to output properly. It simulates a drunken sailor on a board that randomly goes one step to the left or right. At the end of the simulation, the program outputs the percentage of times he fell off the board vs not falling off. My percentage is always zero, and I can't figure out whats wrong with my code.

This function correctly outputs the "experiments" and "fallCount" variable, but always displays "fallCount / experiments" as zero.

This should read "After 2 experiments, sailor fell 1 time, fall percentage was 0.5%"
(if experiments = 2 and fallCount = 1) instead, its 0% every time.

Let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
void  outputExperimentStats(int experiments, int fallCount)
{
cout << "After " << experiments << " experiments, sailor fell "
<< fallCount << " time, fall percentage was " << fallCount / experiments << "%\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using integer division. There are no decimals, so things get truncated. E.g.

```
1 / 2 --> 0  // integer division
```

This is correct, and expected behavior.

To get the behavior you want, use `double` or `float`.

```
1.0 / 2.0 --> 0.5  // double division
```

In your example, you can either change the types of your inputs to `double` or if you want to keep them `int`, you can convert them during the division

```
static_cast<double>(fallCount) / static_cast<double>(experiments)
```